# Wordpress. Modify the css only for the homepage

Tags: css, wordpress

I installed wordpress 3.7. On the home page, which is a static page, I have included a slideshow. For best viewing should remove padding in the global.css file of my theme.

```
#content #respond {
   padding: 1em;
 }
```

The problem is that by removing the padding on # content, I remove it from all the other pages and this is not good.

How do I get the # content without padding only on the home?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to your home page , view the source

look for the opening body tag, for something like

```
<body class="page-template-home">
```

then in you css write

```
.page-template-home #content #respond {
    padding: 1em;
}
```

---

EDIT

you said you have this for body tag on home page in comment

```
 <body class="home page page-id-2 page-template-default logged-in chrome alt-style-blue layout-full has-lightbox">
```

So in your css write the following

```
.home #content #respond {
    padding: 1em;
}
```

That should work for you.

another option would be to write

```
.page-id-2 #content #respond {
     padding: 1em;
}
```

Comment: on my home page i have: <body class="home page page-id-2 page-template-default logged-in chrome alt-style-blue layout-full has-lightbox"> so i used into custom.css:  .page-template-default #content #respond { padding:0 } but not working