# Home Page background image different from other pages

Tags: css, image, background

I have a site with about 7 different pages. I'd like to have two different background images, one for the home page and another that will display on every other page. Does this require Javascript/Jquery or simple css?

As I show below, I set my body to display the background image on the six other pages. Then tried using css directly in my HTML index page and display a different background but it failed.

```
body {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  
background: url(images/hso-palmtree-background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Nope, no JS needed...apply class to the body of the home page and then select and style accordingly.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122994/wordpress-modify-the-css-only-for-the-homepage/21123063#21123063

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a specific class for your body tag on each page.

Say on home:

```
  <body class="home">
```

And on each page

```
 <body class="page-1">
 <body class="page-2">
 ....
```

Then your css could be separated into several rules that would match each body class, specialization

```
/* common body css */
body {
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
} 

/* specialized body for home */
body.home {
   background: url(images/hso-palmtree-background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}

/* specialized body rules for page 1 */
body.page-1 {
   background: url(images/background-for-page-1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
```

and so on...

Answer (score -1):

there alot of ways

make every body have an id or class

or add the background as html `<style>background :imgurl</style>`